# Splitting textarea sentences into array and finding out which sentence changed on keyup()

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

I have a textarea with this content:

```
<textarea id="text">
Hello! Who am I? This is the third sentence. This, is another sentence.
</textarea>
```

Since it's a textarea, it can be focused. I'm trying to find a way to:

1. Separate all sentences inside the textarea into a javascript array. I tried a **$('#text').val().split()** approach, but there is more than just one sentence separator in my example.
2. I also need to know in which sentence the cursor is currently positioned on.

Why, you may ask? I need to process (with a paid API that charges per character) sentences when the user changes their content. If I only make a small change in the 2nd sentence, why should the 1st, 3rd and 4th sentences be submitted? It is of course much less expensive to only submit the 2nd one.

As I previously said, the .split() approach would be perfect if people only used dots to separate sentences, but there are other characters that should also be considered (**!?.**) -- about the second point, i found a function to find de caret position:

```
function doGetCaretPosition (ctrl) {
    var CaretPos = 0;
    if (document.selection) {
        ctrl.focus ();
        var Sel = document.selection.createRange ();
        Sel.moveStart ('character', -ctrl.value.length);
        CaretPos = Sel.text.length;
    } else if (ctrl.selectionStart || ctrl.selectionStart == '0') {
        CaretPos = ctrl.selectionStart;
    }
    return (CaretPos);
}
```

The question is, how does the position help me find the sentence number? All ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way I can see to do this is to split() the str like you mentioned. From my understanding (and not finding any references to this), jQuery doesn't actually have a split() function, however:

```
var str = $('#text').val();
var sentences = str.split(/[.|!|?]\s/gi);
```

So as you can see, javascript's split function allows for regular expressions. The regex however isn't perfect (it's getting late, i'll look into getting a better one tomorrow).

Once you have the sentences it's just a matter of counting the length of each string until you get the caret's position. So get length of first sentence, is it bigger of = to the caret position, if not, get length of second string + first string, is that = or bigger. If it is equal or bigger, then that's the sentence you're on and the index your using is the sentence number.

Comment: that's actually a great approach. i'm not that well-versed in regex, but i tested it and it worked pretty good. of course, if you think that the regex can be improved, that would be great!

Comment: Yeah, the problem I found with the regex is that it doesn't include the punctuation, which may cause a problem if the punctuation is changed

Comment: i added this to the split regex to also grab new lines: var sentences = str.split(/\r\n|\r|\n|[.|!|?]\s/gi);

Comment: @MattR yes, just tested the punctuation issue. Without that character inside the array item value, the sentence length count won't work :s any ideas on that?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't been able to come up with anything. My knowledge with using regexps is very limited.

Comment: @MattR someone helped on that specific issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127132/including-separator-characters-in-split-javascript/11127276 it works great!