# Including separator characters in split (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

This is a textarea. The user can write anything.

```
<textarea id="text">First sentence. Second sentence? Third sentence!
Fourth sentence.

Fifth sentence
</textarea>
```

At the end, i have to split all the text into an array.

```
var sentences = $('#text').val().split(/\r\n|\r|\n|[.|!|?]\s/gi);
```

The issue i'm having, is that the separator characters are not present in the array item values. This is what **sentences** is returning:

```
["First sentence", "Second sentence", "Third sentence", "Fourth sentence", "Fifth sentence"]
```

It should be:

```
["First sentence.", "Second sentence?", "Third sentence!", "", "Fourth sentence.", "", "", "Fifth sentence"]
```

Extra considerations:

- last sentence doesn't require a separator character (it can end at any char)
- if a sentence has more than one separator char, it should also be included in the array item. Example: **second sentence??** should be [...,"second sentence??",...]

Any ideas? Any approach is welcome (not split() necessarily) - **Thanks**!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var re = /[^\r\n.!?]+(:?(:?\r\n|[\r\n]|[.!?])+|$)/gi;
("First sentence.. Second sentence?? Third sentence!!\n"+ "Fourth sentence").match(re).map($.trim)
//["First sentence..", "Second sentence??", "Third sentence!!", "Fourth sentence"]
```

Comment: I really like your solution because it returns trimmed values. However in the testing process i found two extra considerations. I tried to implement the solution by myself without success. Can you give me a hand? The post description has been update above with the extra considerations. Thanks!

Comment: thanks, that fixed the 2nd consideration, the 1st is still not working: last sentence doesn't require a separator character (it can end at any char) / that's kind of an important one because for the nature of my form, the user usually doesn't care about the last sentence closure.

Comment: @andufo wait, you want the last sentence to require a whitespace? I don't think users write a whitespace after last sentence?

Comment: no, I meant that the last user can have any of the already mentioned separator characters (?!.\n etc) or also can have -nothing- for example, this string should return 2 sentences: "first sentence. second sentence" (no extra space at the end, but also no separator character) -- this only applies of course to the last sentence.

Comment: @andufo ah I think I get it now, I have again edited regex and example accordingly (last sentence stops without any separator)

Comment: truly awesome response, you save my day (or may i say my dawn... it is 5am in here). Thanks once again. Accepted answer.

Comment: hi again, sorry to ask for your help one more last time hehe... im having an issue with the new lines. As it turns out, each new line should be represented by an empty array item (i edited the original post). I tried a few approaches by editing your regex but it didn't work. Can you please give me a hand?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12882/discussion-between-andufo-and-esailija)

Answer (score 8):

Use `.match` instead ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)). When you use it with a `/.../g`-type regex, it returns an array of all matches. You just need to modify your regex first:

```
var sentences = $('#text').val().match(/[^\r\n.!?]+(\r\n|\r|\n|[.!?])\s*/gi);
```

​http://jsfiddle.net/kEHhA/3/

Comment: The `\s` at the end makes this require a whitespace after the fourth sentence

Comment: This solution works but fails to discard section numbers like `13.1.2` within a sentence. It counts something like this as 2 extra sentences. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @W.M. In this case, you could check to see if there's a whitespace (`\s`) character after the punctuation symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for your purposes? It looks like you're already using jQuery but if not it should be easy to modify:

```
var sentences = [];
$.each($('#text').val().split(/([^\.\?\!\r\n]+.)\s/gi), function(i, sentence) {
  if(i%2 !== 0) {
    sentences.push(sentence)
  }
});
// sentences = ["First sentence.", "Second sentence?", "Third sentence!", "Fourth sentence."]
```

Edit: Blazemonger's solution is similar but more elegant, using match() instead of split() and therefore not needing the second step of removing the odd elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
var sentences = $('#text').val().split(/\r\n|\r|\n|\s/gi);
```

Comment: This returns `["First", "sentence.", "Second", "sentence?", "Third", "sentence!", "Fourth", "sentence."]`

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy with [look-behinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), but since JavaScript does not support it, my suggestion would be:

Find the white space characters you want to split on and replace them with some dummy character. Then split on that character.

Something like:

```
$('#text').val().replace(/\r\n|\r|\n|([.!?])\s/gi, '$1\0').split(/\0/g);​​​​​
```

*Edit:* Apparently there are better solutions which don't rely on split. I will leave this as alternative however.