# Count sentences in string with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, count, coffeescript

There are already a couple of similar questions:

- [Splitting textarea sentences into array and finding out which sentence changed on keyup()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111801/splitting-textarea-sentences-into-array-and-finding-out-which-sentence-changed-o)
- [JS RegEx to split text into sentences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630408/js-regex-to-split-text-into-sentences)
- [Javascript RegExp for splitting text into sentences and keeping the delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761563/javascript-regexp-for-splitting-text-into-sentences-and-keeping-the-delimiter)
- [Split string into sentences in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914629/split-string-into-sentences-in-javascript)

My situation is a bit different.

I need to **count** the number of sentences in a string.

The closest answer to what I need would be:

```
str.replace(/([.?!])\s*(?=[A-Z])/g, "$1|").split("|")
```

The only problem here is that this RegEx assumes a sentence starts with a capital letter, which may not always be the case.

To be more specific, I would define a sentence as:

- Starting with a letter (capital or not), a number or even a symbol (such as $ or €).
- Ending with a punctuation sign, such as a " . ", a " ? " or a " ! ".

However, if a sentence contains a number, which itself contains a " . " or a " , ", then the sentence should be considered as one sentence and not two.

Last but not least, we can assume that, except the first sentence, a sentence is preceded by a space.

Given a random string, how can I count the number of sentences it contains with Javascript (or CoffeeScript for that matter)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One regex to solve your problem is:

```
\w[.?!](\s|$)
```

The parts are as follows:

```
\w - Word character
\[.?!] - Punctuation as specified.
(\s|$) - Whitespace character OR the end of the string.
```

You may be able to use a character class instead of a group:

```
[\s|$]
```

For the final element, but that isn't working on https://regex101.com/.

Tested on the following:

> Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random **text.** It
>   has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making
>   it over 2000 years **old.** Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at
>   Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure
>   Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going
>   through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the
>   undoubtable **source.** Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and
>   1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 **BC.** This book is a treatise on the
>   theory of ethics, very popular during the **Renaissance.** The first line
>   of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in
>   section 1.10.**32.**

And finds six sentences (bolded the end of sentences, not the actual match). Note that the different grouping might pose a problem if you're depending on it for any reason.

Comment: How to add this in JS?

Comment: Your last 2 sentences are counted as 1 with the example regex. It doesn't match `).`. The corrected regex is `str.match(/[\w|\)][.?!](\s|$)/g).length`

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a much simpler solution.

```js
let text = text + " ";
const count = text.split(". ").length - 1;
console.log(count);
```

Comment: hardly covers all cases

Answer (score 1):

This works if you have a single char at the end of a sentence in a string.

```
const text = ""; //insert your string here
const re = /[.!?]/;
const numOfSentences = text.split(re);
console.log(numOfSentences.length - 1);
```

Comment: Please, specify what exactly is your question.